# Probability density for wavefunction given as infinite superposition of eigenstates

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, hilbert-space, probability, superposition

How do we find the probability density as a function of (x,t), if the wavefunction is expressed as an infinite superposition of eigenstates? When the wavefunction is expressed as a superpostion of merely two eigenstates we end up with some overlap term when we compute the density function. How do we deal with a superposition of more than two eigenstates?

Comment: Why do you think the process is any different? Compute $\rho = \lvert \psi \rvert^2$. It doesn't matter what form $\psi$ is given in.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of an infinite superposition of eigenstates it becomes more complicated but we can still write a general expression for it.

If $$\psi(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \phi_n(x)$$ where the $\phi_n$ are the eigenstates of the Hamiltonian.
The time dependent wavefunction will look like:
$$\Psi(x,t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \phi_n(x) T_n(t)$$ where $T_n = e^{-i E_n t/\hbar}$. So the probability density will be the absolute square of this: 
$$\rho(x,t) = \left|\Psi(x,t)\right|^2 = \sum_{m=0}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n a_m^* \phi_n(x)\phi_m^*(x) T_n(t)T_m^*(t) \\= \sum_{m=0}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n a_m^* \phi_n(x)\phi_m^*(x) \exp\left(i(E_m-E_n)t/\hbar\right)$$

This looks pretty hideous, I'll admit!

Comment: Right, that's what I got. But how do you work with a thing like that? For example, if I want to calculate so simple a thing as the expected value of the position, I end up with an ugly integral.

Comment: Sadly there are a *lot* of ugly integrals in quantum mechanics, although at least some of them can be simplified in some way, for example you may have a degenerate system where $E_n=E_m$ for some $m,n$ which will kill the exponential term, or you may be able to use orthogonality of states as well

Answer (score -1):

In that case, you have a sum of overlaps between a pair of functions having same eigenvalue index. The cross overlap will be zero because of the orthogonality of basis set which is very important.

Answer (score -1):

you can make any state if you properly choose bases as,

$|\Psi> = \alpha|0> + \beta |1>$

where $|0>$ and $|1>$ are assumed as the complete bases. In this case, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the probability amplitude to observe 0 or 1 respectively.

Similarly if the system can be written by a continuous bases, like space $|x>$, any state can be represented as,

$|\Psi> = \int{\rm d}x\Psi(x)|x>$.

The probability amplitude one may find a particle (state) at $x$ is $<x|\Psi> = \Psi(x)$. This is the wave function.

I hope this helps!

Comment: The probability amplitude is $\lvert \psi(x) \rvert^2$, not the wavefunction $\psi(x)$.

Comment: Thanks the comment to my anser. You should check the definition of the probability and the probability amplitude.

Comment: I'm not talking about the probability amplitude - I'm talking about the probability density function, which is the wavefunction squared. And I'm asking about a system that is a superposition of more than two states - see the answer by danimal.

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding. Danimal is correct. And if you want to make the bases orthogonal (to make the equation simpler), you can follow the Gram-Schmidt procedure.